# The redis gem allows user/password symbols to connect to a redis server?

Tags: redis

I'm using the [redis gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/redis) to make a connection to my own [redis](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart) server without verify a valid user/password.

If I execute this:

```
require 'redis'

redis = Redis.new(:host => '33.33.33.10',
                  :port => '6379'
)

puts redis.inspect
puts redis.ping
```

The output is:

```
#<Redis client v3.0.7 for redis://33.33.33.10:6379/0>
PONG
```

All fine, no problems, but how can I use a combination of user and password to verify the valid credentials when a user try to connect to my server.??

I would appreciate a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

See [Redis Security](http://redis.io/topics/security): Redis is designed to be accessed by trusted clients inside trusted environments.

So basically you should do your own user login and only if you trust them, you can let them connect to your Redis server.